# Selecting json values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json object as follows:

```
[{"Id":"1","Item":"Apples","PricePerKilo":"10.00"},
 {"Id":"3","Item":"Oranges","PricePerKilo":"12.00"}]
```

I wish to get the PricePerKilo where the Id is 3.

```
var fruits = jQuery("#products").data('productData');
```

fruits holds the json object by the way...

I will explain what I want to do in SQL, because I find it easier to explain this way

```
SELECT PricePerKilo From fruits WHERE Id = 3 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must loop! (Also, if `fruits` holds the JSON and not the array [it can’t hold both] then you should use `jQuery.parseJSON` on it first.)

```
var i, fruit;

for(i = 0; fruit = fruits[i]; i++) {
    if(fruit.Id == 3)
        break;
}
```

`fruit` will contain either the fruit with the `Id` of `3` or `undefined` if it didn’t exist.

Comment: I like this approach, but wouldn't `fruit` hold the last fruit object if the id didn't exist?

Comment: @Steve: It’s an unusual loop :) Instead of `i < fruits.length`, the condition is `fruit = fruits[i]`. So it exits when `fruit` becomes `undefined`.

Comment: Ah... good call.  But wouldn't that give you a JS error when trying to access `Id` of `undefined`?  Shouldn't it be `if (fruit && fruit.Id ==3)`?

Comment: @Steve: No, the loop will break before that happens. It’s like `while(fruit = fruits[i]) { … }`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nifty little for loop... Learned 2 things in one question! :) Shame a json object isn't an actual object or can't be indexed like an associative array though!

Comment: @Gravy: A JSON object is an actual object! The problem is that `Id` issn’t an index. :)

Comment: Aaah... I think I get it now. The json provided in the question is a json object containing an array. The array index for Apples is 0 and array index for Oranges is 1. Each array index holds name/value pairs. I have to loop through the index to find my required name/value pair?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to loop through your array and select the id that matches:

```
$.each(fruits, function(i, val){
    if (val.Id == 3) {
        // val is now the single fruit object with the id of 3
    }
});
```